# A packaged way to handle signals?

Tags: c++, signals

I have a program for solving a dynamical system. Stripped to its bones, it looks something like this:

```
#include <various_things.h>

double f(double t, double x, double p, double dt);

class Simulator {
  Simulator();
  void solve();

  double solution;
  double time, timeMax, timeStep;
  double parameter;
};

void Simulator::solve()
{
  while (time < timeMax)
  {
    solution = f(time, solution, parameter, timeStep);
    time += timeStep;
    printf("%f %f\n", time, solution);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv)
{
  Simulator* sim = new Simulator(vp);
  if (argc <= 2) exit(-1);
  sim->time = 0;
  sim->solution = atof(argv[1]); // initial condition
  sim->parameter = atof(argv[2]); // 'parameters'
  /* ... */
  sim->solve();
}
```

An initial condition and a parameter are first specified through the arguments. Then `Simulator::solve()` performs a loop which updates the solution.

I wanted to make this more interactive, so that one can pass a `SIGINT` signal and specify a new parameter, for example. So, based on the signal-handling tutorials that I could find, I tried something like this:

```
#include <signal.h>

static void handler(int signum, siginfo_t *siginfo, ucontext_t *context)
{
  /* What does context do? */
  printf("What should the new parameter value be? [%f]", sim->parameter);
  char buffer[1024];
  gets(buffer);
  if (strcmp(buffer, "\n") != 0)
    sim->parameter = atof(buffer);
  sim->solve();
}

/* This is now declared in the global scope. */
Simulator* sim;

int main(int argc, char* argv)
{
  /* I don't really understand how this bit works. */
  struct sigaction act;
  memset(&act, '\0', sizeof(act));
  act.sa_sigaction = &handler;
  act.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO; // what?

  if (sigaction(SIGINT, &act, NULL) < 0)
  {
    /* Under what circumstances would this happen? */
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not handle signal.\n");
    perror("sigaction");
    return 1;
  }

  sim = new Simulator;
  if (argc <= 2) exit(-1);
  sim->time = 0;
  sim->solution = atof(argv[1]);
  sim->parameter = atof(argv[2]);
  /* ... */
  sim->solve();
 }
```

I think this code works. But I have some concerns about it:

- I am worried about declaring `sim` in the global scope, but I don't know how else to get `handler()` to know about it.
- Suppose I want to use `Simulator` in a different program. At the moment, the signal-handling is done in `main()`; would it be possible to make it intrinsic to `Simulator` (so that any program using `Simulator` will catch the signal)?

Comment: first of all, you can't really do much inside signal handler - to check which system calls are signal safe check [man 7 signal](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html). So `printf` and `gets` should not be used. With the second question - what do you mean by "different program"? Do you want to include signal handling in class and hide it under its implementation, so everyone who's using/linking to it will have signal handler set up?

Comment: @zoska That's right, yes - I'd like to have the signal caught by each instance of `Simulator` (for example, to get all of them to print their state on receiving a `SIGINT`). One way I thought about it was to put the `sigaction` call inside the constructor `Simulator::Simulator`, but that won't work because `handler` works with the particular instance `sim`, not any other instance.

Comment: So in one process you want to have multiple instances of Simulator and pass information to each one of them, when signal reaches the process?

Comment: Moreover, hiding signal handling under library implementation is very risky. You don't know if user of your class is not using the same signal or some other way of handling signals like signal fd, which could make your code or user of your code not working. What exactly do you want to achieve?